# How to change the PVID of a device and still be able to import the Volume Group in AIX?

Tags: lvm, aix

I have 3 disks that are copies of other disks so they have the same PVID's. I would like to change the PVID of those disks and import the volume group but as I understand the VGDA information on the disks references the old PVID's.

How can I change the PVIDs and update the VG information to import the VG?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

The command recreatevg can be used after the PVIDs are cleared and new PVIDs assigned. All of the devices part of the volume group must be passed as part of the argument and the name of volume group can be given.

```
recreatevg -y new_vgname hdiskX hdiskY hdiskZ
```